# Cant find database when app starts

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im trying to do a simple example using my own SQLite database, android and greenDAO generator to generate classes for my android app.

My database file is defined this way:

1) Create a database called "OneTableDB" (without extension, SQLite 3) with the following structure:

Entity: Professor

- professorID: primarykey
- name: text
- age: int

Entity: android_metadata

- locale: text

Then i populated android_metadata with the value 'en_US', and the entity with few rows.

2) placed on my Android app structure inside: proj_root/databases/
Full path to database file: proj_root/databases/OneTableDB

3)i have a method to check whether database exists or not (in my case, it has to exist, since i placed inside databases folder)

```
private boolean databaseExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;
    try {
        String databasePath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        File f = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        f.exists();

        sqliteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (sqliteDatabase != null) {
        sqliteDatabase.close();
    }
    return sqliteDatabase != null ? true : false;
}

//DB_PATH = /data/data/com.myapp.android_dao_tests/databases/

//DB_NAME = OneTableDB
```

debugging on f.exists(), it returns false value and then breaks on

```
sqliteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

During the debugging i used adb shell to check if the path was right, and in fact i can navigate to /data/data/com.myapp.android_dao_tests/ and there is no databases folder!

Any idea how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: If your database doesn't exist, it was probably just never created. I would look for the problem there - can you post the code showing how you create your DB?

Comment: i have created the database outside the android project. I have created this DB manually. and copied to databases folder inside my project.

Comment: So you put the DB file there manually yourself, but next time you check, the file is gone? Did you install the app only after you copied the file there? Try to first install the app, then copy the DB file to the databases/ folder, and only then running the app (I expect the app would delete its internal folder (/data/data/com.myapp.android_dao_tests) when installing, so this could be the cause for the lost DB file).

Comment: i have managed to copy the database with success, but now my problem is that it just copies the structure, and not the values! :/

Comment: You're creating the DB on your machine, creating tables, inserting values, and then you copy the DB to the databases/ folder in the device. Then you run the app, and it finds the DB there. Is this correct thus far? How did you conclude now that the values aren't there?

Comment: yes. I have made some modification on my code, and i manage to create (by copying bytes) the database on /data/data/com.myapp.android_dao_tests/databases/. To check if the database was created with my schema, and if it was populated i used adb shell, then "sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp.android_dao_tests/databases/OneTableDB.sqlite", and doing ".tables" i see that i have the 2 tables there, and after this i do "select * from PROFESSOR" and there is no values there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47872/discussion-between-paf-and-user1907954)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB "template" is saved in the assets/ folder, in order for it to be bundled in the apk. The code then copies the DB from assets/ to databases/ to make it accessible as a regular SQLite DB.

After further investigation, it seems like Android refuses to acknowledge the new DB as its own. Apparently, the built-in DB mechanism wasn't meant to be used this way.

The correct way to approach it is by keeping the data in textual format in assets/ so that if the app starts and finds there's no DB, it will create the schema itself, and populate it with the data in the text files from the assets/ folder.